# How to change background image from user input (URL) using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom

How I'm supposed to change the HTML background image using the input user, the input is URL Link.

```html
    <input type="text" id="value">
    <button onclick="fun()">Change</button>
```

I tried something like this but it does not work.

```js
function fun (){
      var value = document.getElementById("value").value;
      document.body.style.background = 'url(value)';
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its because you are not using the value of "value". You need to concat the variable between the string.

Try this:

```html
<input type="text" id="value">
<button onclick="fun()">Change</button>
```

```js
function fun(){
      var value = document.getElementById("value").value;
      document.body.style.background = "url("+ value + ")";;
}
```

Comment: @Hunali if it helped could you please mark it as the answer? :D